# Flutter listview is not visible

Tags: flutter

```
 Widget servicesListview() {
    return Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA)),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: menServicesList.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Text(menServicesList[index].name);
                }),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

I am implementing listview in my flutter project whenever i call this method list is not visible.The page becomes blank,help me to solve this

Answer (score 31):

I have a same problem. 
The `ListView.builder` don't work inside a `Column`, this necessary use the `Expanded`.
The `Expanded` widget allows you to expand and fill the space with the relative widget.

See this:

```
child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
         child: ListView.builder(
            .......
         )
      )
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 8):

Wrap your ListView inside of a `Expanded` or a `Container` widget, if you use a `Container`, you'll need to set a height/width.

This happens because `ListView` doesn't have a height/width property to edit.

**EDIT**

Don't forget to return your Text inside the itemBuilder property.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing the `return` statement in your `itemBuilder`

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Text(menServicesList[index].name);
}),
```

or

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Text(menServicesList[index].name)),
```

Answer (score 2):

If you remove Column widget from the ListView, the list will definitely appear 
and if you want to give a decoration property to each element of a ListView.

```
Widget servicesListview() {
  return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: menServicesList.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: const Color(0xFFEAEAEA)),
            child: Text(menServicesList[index].name)
        );
      })
}
```

Comment: i tried the code which you updated its not working the page is still remains blank